# K3s Ansible Playbook - Define multiple ansible_users

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-inventory, k3s

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster using k3s via Ansible using this code: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible.

I have to change `ansible_user` inside `inventory/my-cluster/group_vars/all.yml` to match my environment. The problem here is that I have an ubuntu pc as master (ansible_user: antonis) and two raspberry pis as workers (ansible_user: pi).

**all.yml**

```
---
k3s_version: v1.17.5+k3s1
ansible_user: antonis
systemd_dir: /etc/systemd/system
master_ip: "{{ hostvars[groups['master'][0]]['ansible_host'] | default(groups['master'][0]) }}"
extra_server_args: ""
extra_agent_args: ""
```

If I execute `ansible-playbook site.yml -i inventory/my-cluster/hosts.ini` I get the followng error as expected:

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: antonis@192.168.xxx.xxx
```

The reason is that the user in case of workers is pi and not antonis.

Then I pass the user inside host.ini:

```
[master]
192.168.xxx.xxx

[node]
pi@192.168.xxx.xxx
pi@192.168.xxx.xxx


[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node
```

However I get the following:

```
fatal: [pi@192.168.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'token'"}
fatal: [pi@192.168.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'token'"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.xxx.xxx               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pi@192.168.xxx.xxx           : ok=15   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=8    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pi@192.168.xxx.xxx           : ok=15   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=8    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to do it like this: ```192.168.xxx.xxx ansible_user=pi```

Comment: Do you mean in hosts.ini file? Like 192.168.1.70 ansible_user=antonis? No it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your `host.ini` like this:

```
master ansible_port=22 hostname=master.example.com ansible_host=192.168.xxx.xxx ansible_user=antonis
node1 ansible_port=22 hostname=node1.example.com ansible_host=192.168.xxx.xxx ansible_user=pi
node2 ansible_port=22 hostname=node2.example.com ansible_host=192.168.xxx.xxx ansible_user=pi

[master]
master

[node]
node1
node2

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node
```

Important keys for you are `ansible_user`, `ansible_host`. Others `ansible_port`, `hostname` are optional, so only if you need them.